# How to add "List-Unsubscribe" in email header using CakeEmail component

Tags: cakephp

I've tried the below, but it didn't works

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->addHeaders(array("List-Unsubscribe"=>"<$url>"));
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you